# C and MinGW: How do I fix my "No such file or directory" error?

Tags: c, mingw

I have made a python "compiler" that helps me compile my C code with gcc, for example it fetches all my header files and source files. So my cmd commmand is `gcc {headers} {source} -o {build_dir}/build.exe -lgdi32 -w` where `{headers}` is a string like `-Ipath/to/headers/foo.h -Ipath/to/other/headers.foo2.h` and where `{source}` is the same but with .c files. It seems that the compiler finds the header files, but when compiling my code it fails.

(btw I am trying to make a portable programming environment on my flash drive so python and mingw are both portable)

This is the error: `fatal error: test.h: No such file or directory #include "test.h"`

[My project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBq7B.png)

I have put the third party library files into the mingw directory instead of making a custom one and then linking it in the gcc command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-I` option takes the path to the directory containing the header files or more specifically with an argument `-Ipath` and a directive `#include<a/b.h>`, the compiler will try to look for the header file at `path/a/b.h`.

So you should not give it paths to header files, only to the directory or directories relative to which you use include directives.

Comment: I thought that would maybe be the problem. But the thing is that when I first tried this, it worked instead of giving me this error

Comment: @1NilusNilus I can't tell from your question why it worked before, but it is wrong to pass full header paths to `-I`.

Comment: okay thank you for your answer